# download dialog not displaying

Tags: node.js, express, download

I can't for the life of me get a download dialog to pop up instead of just directly downloading a file in my node application.

My troubled code looks like this:

```
app.get(`/search/download`, function(req, res){
    var request = require(`request`);
    request({uri: `http://some.csv.file`, headers: {`content-type`: `text/csv`}}
        , function(err, response, body) {

        res.set(`Content-Disposition`, `attachment; filename="search-results.csv"`);
        res.set(`Content-Type`, `text/csv`);
        res.send(body);
    });
}
```

No matter what I change, both Chrome and Safari immediately download the file instead of bringing up a save dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Content-Type from `text/csv` to `application/octet-stream`.

```
app.get(`/search/download`, function(req, res){
    var request = require(`request`);
    request({uri: `http://some.csv.file`, headers: {`content-type`: `text/csv`}}
        , function(err, response, body) {

        res.set(`Content-Disposition`, `attachment; filename="search-results.csv"`);
        res.set(`Content-Type`, `application/octet-stream`);
        res.send(body);
    });
}
```

Comment: I must have something else wrong, because this also immediately downloads the file instead of triggering the download dialog.

Comment: After some more research, it looks like I also needed to turn some settings on in chrome to turn on the save as dialog. But this is what I needed on the server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do the same thing (if the served file is static):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/some.csv.file', {
    setHeaders: function(res, path) {
        res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="search-results.csv"');
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    }
})
```