# Send a file from NodeJS as response to Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, jquery-ajaxq

I'm developing a web application where user clicks on a button, and a Jquery AJAX call goes to NodeJS server which in turn fetches the records from Elastic Search. I want these records to be written into a CSV file and send this file to AJAX as response being available for download on browser. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');    
var stream = fs.createReadStream(pathToFile);
stream.on('error', function(){ 
    console.log('404  -------- ', pathToFile);
});
stream.pipe(res);


var destroy = require('destroy'); // nam i destroy --save
var onFinished = require('on-finished'); // nam i on-finished --save
onFinished(res, function (err) {
    destroy(stream)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".export").on('click',function(){
    var project_id="<?php echo $_GET['project_id'];?>";
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: 'https://work.readycontacts.com/True_Validate/download_file.php',
        data: "project_id=" + project_id,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
return false;
});
```

});

export is the function that is bean click and you can replace download_file.php with your  nodejs download code file

Comment: then to download the file using nodejs refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558126/ask-user-where-to-save-file-with-node-js   and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847416/download-dialog-not-displaying